# Enviar email se valor atender a um critério na coluna

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Tenho um código que lê um valor "sim" em uma coluna e envia um email se esse valor estiver lá. Porém, o `if` que eu criei para isso envia mesmo se o valor "sim" não está lá. O código está abaixo. Meu `if` parece estar correto.

```
for (var i=0;i<numRows-startRow;i++){
    var lembretePeriodico = dataRange[i][10]; 

    if (lembretePeriodico  = "sim") {
      var emailAddress = dataRange[i][7] + ", " + dataRange[i][1] + ", " + dataRange[i][9];
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu operador `=` está incorreto. O sinal `=` é de atribuição, você deve usar `==` para verificar igualdade:

```
if (lembretePeriodico == "sim") {
```